# Xamarin.Android Error with Ical.net Xamarin Version

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, icalendar

I'm working on an Android App with Xamarin and I need to read Data from Ics Files, On Windows i did this with Ical.net (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net) and now there was a Xamarin-Alpha released for this package.

But when i install this package into my project and try to compile i get the following error: [Xamarin Compile Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDG8A.png)

I already wrote a Mail to the Author of Ical.net but he said it isn't the fault of the Nuget Package...

Please help me since i'm new to Android App Programming...
I'm using the Newest version of the Xamarin Framework and want to target Android 6.0

Comment: This package looks like it's supported in PCL Profile 111. It might seem that the `Xamarin.Android` linker is stripping the .dll if it cannot support it directly. How are you installing the package? Into what type of project?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

My Project is a Blank Android App (Xamarin.Android) I'm targeting Android 6.0 and have ALL Sdks installed. I'm installing it over the pre-release channel of the Nuget paket manager. (Right click on project manage nuget packages) How should i install it if this is false?

Comment: Seeing that there isn't a direct `monodroid` target in the NuGet package, I believe you would have to put this into a PCL of profile 111 and then reference that in your Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: I have never done something like this before, how do i do this ?

Comment: See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/